# como abrir mais de uma View em uma controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma controller chamada Pedido:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pedido()
{
    return View();
}
```

Como abrir mais de uma *View* em uma *Controller*?
Ao chamar uma *Controller* gostaria de abrir duas views.

Obs: Gostaria de abrir e abas diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

No `controller`, creio que não consiga retornar duas views de uma vez. 
Não sei se é o seu caso, mas consegue redirecionar para rotas diferentes, 
`return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "controlador", action = "ação" });`.

Answer (score 0):

Até onde eu sei não tem como você abrir duas *Views*.

A *Action* do seu *Controller* deve retornar uma *View* apenas.

Porém na sua *View* você pode criar [abas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs).

Answer (score 0):

A action retorna somente uma view, o que dá para fazer é nessa view chamar um ajax que abra a nova view em outra aba mas... não sei se é o melhor a se fazer.

Answer (score 0):

O **controller** permite direcionar **apenas a uma view**. Porém você pode, no `load` da sua view, abrir uma nova aba com javascript.

Em sua `view`, adicione essa função a um bloco de `script`:

```
function novaaba() {
    window.open("SUA_URL_AQUI", '_blank');
}
```

E então a chame no `load` do seu `body`, dessa forma:

```
<body onLoad="novaaba();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro da sua view de pedidos você terá que chamar uma view parcial.

```
<fieldset>
     <lengend>Itens do pedido</legend>
     @Html.Partial("ItemDoPedido", idPedido)
</fieldset>
```